# How to concatenate strings in list python

Tags: python, list, unique, lines

This prints the list correctly, but it prints it 7 times. I need to print my list only 2 times. I think the list is printing 7 times because there are 7 strings in the list.

Is there a way to only make it print my "custom" list a certain number of times? Because I want to use all these words, but on different lines, and vary each time they are used.

```
lyrics = ['Ring', 'Gering', 'ding', 'dingeringeding!', 'Wa', 'pa', 'pow!']

for y in lyrics:
    print (lyrics[0] +' ' + (lyrics[2] + ' ') * 3 + lyrics[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

use `range`, you have `seven` elements in your list so you iterate `seven` times with `for y in lyrics`:

```
for _ in range(2): # two iterations, prints two times
    print (lyrics[0] +' ' + (lyrics[2] + ' ') * 3 + lyrics[3])
```

It is probably nicer to use `str.format`:

```
for _ in range(2): # two iterations, prints two times
    print ("{} {} {}".format(lyrics[0] ,lyrics[2] * 3, lyrics[3] )
```

Which if you don't mind an extra newline can simply be multiplied:

```
In [36]:  print ("{} {} {}\n".format(lyrics[0] ,lyrics[2] * 3, lyrics[3] )* 2)
Ring dingdingding dingeringeding!
Ring dingdingding dingeringeding!
```

Comment: Zak, you should learn about the join method of strings which concatenates the strings of a list with a specified separator.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, your answer includes the first element which is incorrect

Comment: It should include the first element as it corresponds with `lyrics[0]` in your answer.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi   I meant `lyrics[1]`, you cannot join and skip

Comment: Fixed it, but I don't know it's any more concise.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, I think in this case str.format is the nicest option